# Does Dispel Magic work on a self-targeting spell cast by an artifact and emanating from within an antimagic field?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic, antimagic-field

A character has a sentient artifact able to cast [*Holy Aura*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/holy-aura). Another character casts [*Antimagic Field*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/antimagic-field) and the two effects overlap, so that the origins of both spells are within both spell effects.

Can someone cast [*Dispel Magic*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/dispel-magic) on the *Holy Aura* effect since its radius (30ft) exceeds that of the *Antimagic Field* (10ft)?

The argument raised against being able to dispel it, is that since the effect is active on the artifact, then it is the artifact that must be targeted, differentiating this case from a *Grease* spell for example.

---

According to *Antimagic Field*'s description, the *Holy Aura* works within its radius in this case, because:

> Spells and other magical effects, except those created by an artifact or a deity, are suppressed in the sphere and can't protrude into it

Comment: Hi alxs. You don't need to signal your edits inside a post, because the edit history serves that purpose. Also, italics are the conventional formatting for spells in D&D 5e; code blocks should be reserved for code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### The *dispel magic* spell targets magical effects, not their points of origin

The [*dispel magic*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/dispel-magic) spell states:

> Choose one creature, object, or magical effect within range. Any spell of 3rd level or lower on the target ends. [...]

So while the caster of *dispel magic* could not target the artifact itself because [*antimagic field*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/antimagic-field) states:

> [...] Spells and other magical effects, such as magic missile and charm person, that target a creature or an object in the sphere have no effect on that target. [...]

This does not prevent the caster of *dispel magic* from targeting the *magical effect* that is *outside* of the *antimagic field*. Thus the caster could target the portion of *holy aura* that it outside the *antimagic field*, thereby ending the spell without ever needing to target its point of origin, which cannot itself be targeted.

---

A rather unrelated sidenote, there *are* times in the rules where a magical effect can be dispelled without having to target its point of origin (besides *dispel magic*): the [*darkness*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/darkness) and [*daylight*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/daylight) spells:

> If any of this spell's area overlaps with an area of light created by a spell of 2nd level or lower, the spell that created the light is dispelled.

> If any of this spell's area overlaps with an area of darkness created by a spell of 3rd level or lower, the spell that created the darkness is dispelled.